# Using Google Chrome Web Inspector changes page layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've seen this consistently now when using display: inline-block in Google Chrome. If I right-click and "Inspect Element", it will change the layout of the page, or the width of that element. It's as if it changes the element properties simply by inspecting them. It's frustrating to debug because I'm currently getting rendering bugs with inline-block elements, but, of course, I can't inspect them and tweak their properties, because they magically "fix" themselves if they're inspected.

Anyone had this happen or know of a workaround? Couldn't find anything on the web that described this.

Comment: Can you provide a working example?